# sort nginx logs with loki logql against request_time field

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

this is my logql query

```
{namespace="ingress-nginx"} 
   | json | http_host="admin.site.com" and request_time > 20 and status!="499" 
   | line_format "status={{.status}}\t request_time={{.request_time}}\t {{.request}}"
```

I get the following output

```
2022-03-17 11:47:58 
status=200   request_time=21.346     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery?after_save=1 HTTP/2.0
2022-03-17 11:47:54 
status=200   request_time=26.639     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery?after_save=1 HTTP/2.0
2022-03-17 11:47:45 
status=200   request_time=26.036     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery?after_save=1 HTTP/2.0
2022-03-17 11:47:43 
status=200   request_time=25.548     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery?after_save=1 HTTP/2.0
2022-03-17 03:22:29 
status=200   request_time=22.950     GET /admin/locations/deliveryapproval HTTP/2.0
2022-03-17 03:22:28 
status=200   request_time=22.685     GET /admin/locations/deliveryapproval HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 18:53:05 
status=200   request_time=20.875     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 16:28:32 
status=200   request_time=24.673     GET /admin/report/dailyproduction HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 16:28:16 
status=200   request_time=25.315     GET /admin/report/dailyproduction HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 16:27:04 
status=200   request_time=21.222     GET /admin/payment HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 16:22:09 
status=200   request_time=55.375     GET /admin/membermanagement/routemanager HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 16:21:57 
status=200   request_time=25.150     GET /admin/report HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:26:44 
status=200   request_time=30.300     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery?after_save=1 HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:26:43 
status=200   request_time=32.443     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:26:38 
status=200   request_time=34.245     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:26:31 
status=200   request_time=35.504     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:26:09 
status=200   request_time=32.549     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:26:06 
status=200   request_time=31.524     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:25:56 
status=200   request_time=25.084     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:25:09 
status=200   request_time=21.661     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:25:09 
status=200   request_time=21.467     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:20:35 
status=200   request_time=56.433     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:20:06 
status=200   request_time=36.239     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery?after_save=1 HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:19:53 
status=200   request_time=26.146     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:19:14 
status=200   request_time=21.654     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery?after_save=1 HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 15:19:11 
status=200   request_time=21.311     GET /admin/membermanagement/routedelivery HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 14:32:03 
status=200   request_time=20.591     GET /index.php HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 14:27:17 
status=200   request_time=20.837     GET /index.php HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 14:20:15 
status=200   request_time=21.976     POST /index.php HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 14:20:14 
status=200   request_time=21.630     POST /index.php HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 14:20:14 
status=200   request_time=20.733     POST /index.php HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 14:19:57 
status=200   request_time=20.458     POST /index.php HTTP/2.0
2022-03-16 14:17:39 
status=200   request_time=22.275     POST / HTTP/2.0
```

is it possible to sort it by request_time?